# Too much time when starting Intent (to disable Home button)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-homebutton

I downloaded this [tutorial](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/) to disable home button, the problem is : when I press my home button the activity take too much time to restart (4 seconds).

I tried to replace the service by putting :

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    Intent i = getIntent();
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);

    //disable rencent app button
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    activityManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), 0);

    super.onPause();
}
```

but it's the same, the activity take nearly 5 seconds to restart (in 5 seconds you have the time to go to settings or else and do what you want)

Is it ok that it takes that much time to start an Intent?

Answer (score 1):

Add this lines in your Manifest.xml file

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Yeah it works. But is their a way to not ask the user if he want to set launcher as your app ? And can is there a way in programme to stop using the home button as my app ?

Comment: You cannot disable home button as far as i know, plus this is just a hack that works perfectly to stop user going out of your application.

Comment: I know, I hate the guy at Android that had the idea of the 4.0 maj... But you didn't answer me, I think I will use this hack but I want to implements a button that permit the user to quit app, so to stop using the intent filter that block the launcher as my app. Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Can you explain "idea of the 4.0 maj... " ? and what exactly you want to achieve, also please explain your previous comment  @Kolopox

Comment: I meant that in previous version it was really easy to disable home button ^^ And what I want achieve is : First, when the MainActivty start : I want the message "Do you want to set this app as launcher" to be displayed whithout the need to press the home button to do it. Second, I want that when the user press a button, the home button now start the real home as befor he executed my programme.

Answer (score 0):

adb shell monkey -p com.android.chrome -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1

adb shell monkey -p com.android.settings -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1

adb shell monkey -p com.sec.android.app.launcher -c android.intent.category.MONKEY 1